# Compare data in two unequal panda series & interpolate with respect to one column in first frame,

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have data in two csv files which appears as

```
Time        Mode
0.052104276 
0.323285824 1300
0.499667125 1900
0.581918299 2300
1.426129824 
1.629840644 1000
2.28781633  1500
2.533690634 
3.359366932 1300

.....
81852

**********

Time    Mode    X           Y
0   1000    4187.47131  1150.046926
0   1300    4139.944866 1286.535598
0   1500    4030.914098 1191.252468
0   1700    4098.956464 1132.026224
1   1000    4187.487988 1150.114368
1   1300    4139.962264 1286.602861
1   1500    4030.963927 1191.426078
1   1700    4098.909471 1131.851833
2   1000    4187.504664 1150.18181
2   1300    4139.979661 1286.670125
2   1500    4031.013754 1191.599689
2   1700    4098.862477 1131.677442
3   1000    4187.521341 1150.249252
.....
345896
```

First, am comparing values for Mode in both of frames. find the location where they are equal and then substituting the data in second frame from first frame iterating over the length of time in second frame.

This is how am doing ..

```
modeA = df1['Mode']
modeB = df2['Mode']
timeA = df1['Time']
timeB = df2['Time]
tru_x = df1['X']
tru_y = df1['Y']

def data():

     n = min(len(modeA), len(modeB))
     out_idx = np.flatnonzero(modeA[:n] == modeB[:n])
     return(out_idx)

out_idx = data()
trk_time_vec = timeA[out_idx]
trux = tru_x[out_idx]
truy = tru_y[out_idx]

N = len(df1['Time'])

for idx, x in enumerate(range(N)):

    x0 = ((trux.subtract(trux.shift(1), axis=0, fill_value=1) / (trk_time_vec.subtract(trk_time_vec.shift(1), axis=0, fill_value=0))) * 
    (timeA - timeB) + trux )[x]

    y0 = ((truy.subtract(truy.shift(1), axis=0, fill_value=1) / (trk_time_vec.subtract(trk_time_vec.shift(1), axis=0, fill_value=0))) * 
    (timeA - timeB) + truy)[x]

    print(x0, y0)
```

Problem is x0 & y0 values are random numbers with negative numbers. Is there an alternative approach where the values returned from out_idx is  maximum and values are not -inf or nan?

Expected Result:

```
Time        Mode X           Y 
0.323285824 1300 4139.944866 1286.535598
1.629840644 1000 4187.487988 1150.114368
2.28781633  1500 4031.013754 1191.599689
```

``

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Setup test data:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data_1 = StringIO("""
Time Mode
0.052104276 
0.323285824 1300
0.499667125 1900
0.581918299 2300
1.426129824 
1.629840644 1000
2.28781633 1500
2.533690634 
""")

# load data into data frame
df_1 = pd.read_csv(data_1, sep=' ')

data_2 = StringIO("""
Time Mode X Y
0 1000 4187.47131 1150.046926
0 1300 4139.944866 1286.535598
0 1500 4030.914098 1191.252468
1 1000 4187.487988 1150.114368
1 1300 4139.962264 1286.602861
1 1500 4030.963927 1191.426078
2 1000 4187.504664 1150.18181
2 1300 4139.979661 1286.670125
2 1500 4031.013754 1191.599689
3 1000 4187.521341 1150.249252
""")

# load data into data frame
df_2 = pd.read_csv(data_2, sep=' ')
```

First You need to remove duplicate Mode values from first data set where you get Time, then just use [pandas merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and relocate columns:

```
df = pd.merge(df_2, df_1, on=['Mode'], how='inner')
df.insert(loc=0, column='Time', value=df['Time_y'])
df = df.drop(['Time_x', 'Time_y'], axis=1
```

Output:

```
       Time  Mode            X            Y
0  1.629841  1000  4187.471310  1150.046926
1  1.629841  1000  4187.487988  1150.114368
2  1.629841  1000  4187.504664  1150.181810
3  1.629841  1000  4187.521341  1150.249252
4  0.323286  1300  4139.944866  1286.535598
5  0.323286  1300  4139.962264  1286.602861
6  0.323286  1300  4139.979661  1286.670125
7  2.287816  1500  4030.914098  1191.252468
8  2.287816  1500  4030.963927  1191.426078
9  2.287816  1500  4031.013754  1191.599689
```

Comment: Pardon me if am wrong.. what I intended was to match time in dataset df_2 with df_1 and only get those values  from df_2 which closely matched. Merge is comparing & getting those values along with others. (it's not filtering but populating df with all the other values in Mode) Also, there are no duplicates to be removed...  what i was trying to achieve..                                                                               ### Time        Mode X           Y 
0.323285824 1300 4139.944866 1286.535598
1.629840644 1000 4187.487988 1150.114368
2.28781633  1500 4031.013754 1191.599689